# There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azureportal, web-chat

I deployed the bot code to the azure , Test in webchat option nothing I am getting and in the channels I am getting the below error.

```
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout
```

The bot code works fine in the emulator but getting error in the portal. So how to resolve this problem?

The id's and Bot Channel Registration everything is correct still getting the error.

Comment: How are you deploying the bot on Azure? Can you check the [deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#deploy-your-bot) steps if you missed out on some step? Is the messaging endpoint configured correct?Also, check the [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation to narrow down on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to help you get started:

- You need to check how you are deploying your web app bot to Azure. Refer to the deployment steps [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-basic-deploy?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#deploy-your-bot) to see if you missed any of the steps.
- If your bot is hosted elsewhere, then you will need to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-bot-service-4.0) your bot.
- Check if you have correctly configured your messaging endpoint. It should be in the format `https://yourbotname.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`. Also, double-check if your appID and appPassword are configured correctly.
- Try redeploying the bot again by creating a new Bot Channels Registration or on a different resource group/subscription to see if the problem persists.
- Also, try deploying another bot within the same resource group/subscription to narrow down if the issue is within the bot or with the resources.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps others as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have, like me, entered an incorrect Language Resource Key because the tutorial doesn't tell you where to find it.

To obtain the Language Resource Key required for creating a bot using the Language Studio, you can follow these steps:

1. Log in to the Azure portal and navigate to the Language Understanding resource you created for your bot.
2. Go to the "Keys and Endpoint" tab.
3. Either of the keys on here seem to work.

I found the answer on this page although I didn't need to create the key:

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1275947/where-to-get-language-resource-key-for-bot-creatio

tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/question-answering/tutorials/bot-service